# Passing navigation from function to component throws Typerror

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following function:

```
export default function InstitutionInfoScreen({route, navigation}) {
        const { title, image, logo, location, phone, email } = route.params;
        return (
        <ScrollView >
            <View style={styles.whiteContainer}>
                <InstItem navigation={navigation}/>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    ); 
}
```

Turns out I want InstItem to get the navigation parameter, because I need it for my SliderEntry component.
InstItem looks like this:

```
class InstItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeSlide: SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM
        };
    }
    _renderItemWithParallax ({item, index}, parallaxProps) {
        return (
            <SliderEntry
            navigate={this.props.navigation}. <-- THIS IS THE ISSUE
            type="institution"
            data={item}
            even={(index + 1) % 2 === 0}
            parallax={true}
            parallaxProps={parallaxProps}
            />
        );
    }
    render(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.whiteContainer}>
            <Carousel
                ref={c => this._slider1Ref = c}
                data={DATA2}
                renderItem={this._renderItemWithParallax}
                sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
                itemWidth={itemWidth}
                hasParallaxImages={true}
                firstItem={SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM}
                inactiveSlideScale={0.94}
                inactiveSlideOpacity={0.7}
                // inactiveSlideShift={20}
                containerCustomStyle={styles.slider}
                contentContainerCustomStyle={styles.sliderContentContainer}
                loop={true}
                loopClonesPerSide={2}
                onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ activeSlide: index }) }
            />
            <Pagination
                dotsLength={DATA2.length}
                activeDotIndex={this.state.activeSlide}
                containerStyle={styles.paginationContainer}
                dotColor={'rgba(46, 49, 49, 1)'}
                dotStyle={styles.paginationDot}
                inactiveDotColor={colors.navyblue}
                inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
                inactiveDotScale={0.6}
                carouselRef={this._slider1Ref}
                tappableDots={!!this._slider1Ref}
            />
        </View>
    );
    }
}
```

However I always get:

```
typeerror undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')
```

I´ve tried to use "navigation" directly instead of "this.props.navigation" but that doesn't work either. How can I fix this?

Comment: probably 'this' is not accessible try _renderItemWithParallax =({item, index}, parallaxProps) =>{...declaration}

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.